# Missing partial comments/_comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder] }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As I am new to Ruby. after running the localhost URL I am getting this error.
for this line . which is in the `show.html.erb` file

> `<%= render @article.comments %>`

```
Showing D:/RailProject/App/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #14 raised:

Missing partial comments/_comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.

Searched in:
  * "D:/RailProject/App/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.3/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.3/app/views"
```

I have this code in comments_controller.rb :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: :destroy
    def create
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end
  
    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
      @comment.destroy
      redirect_to article_path(@article), status: 303
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
      @comment.destroy
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end
  
    private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :status)
      end end
```

I have this code in show.html.erb :

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p><%= @article.body %></p>

<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article), data: {
                    turbo_method: :delete,
                    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
                  } %></li>
</ul>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

I have _comments.html.erb :

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Destroy Comment", [comment.article, comment], data: {
                turbo_method: :delete,
                turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
              } %>
</p>
```

Comment: Reread the error message, and then reread your filename. You have not named your file correctly.

Comment: What was your most recent edit supposed to accomplish, besides to destroy the code in your question? You injected dozens of random spaces after underscores, rendering all of your code as a heap of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file called `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` so Rails can use it to render each of your comments. This is what you're asking it to do when you write `<%= render @article.comments %>`. For each element in the collection you passed to `render`, Rails will try to render a partial, and the path to the partial is derived from the name of the model.

If `@article.comments` contains 3 records with ids `1, 2, 3`, and if
if your `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` contains the following...

```html
<h1>Comment <%= comment.id %></h1>
```

Then Rails would render this three times, once for each comment, and produce the following:

```html
<h1>Comment 1</h1>
<h1>Comment 2</h1>
<h1>Comment 3</h1>
```